# Retrofit null response after publishing app

Tags: android, retrofit2

When I install the app from android studio. The app works fine. But after publishing the app it's not working fine.

Here what I m doing is:-
on android studio install, I hit a login API and in the response server sends a token for user login.And i getting this token successfully. But when I publish the app on google play store and the user tries to login I m getting token 'null' in the response of server. And the response code is 200 ok.

> And on postman everything working fine and also on the Apple app.

this is my first project. Please help me I tired now from this.
Can you guys tell me why it's happening.?

[image: Here is a response screenshot of user login on the published app]

> Here is my Model Class And Key or Variable Name is 100% okay.

```
    public class LoginRegistrationModel {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private String success;

    @SerializedName("firstname")
    @Expose
    private String firstname;

    @SerializedName("lastname")
    @Expose
    private String lastname;

    @SerializedName("profile_image")
    @Expose
    private String profile_image;

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setProfile_image(String profile_image) {
        this.profile_image = profile_image;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public String getProfile_image() {
        return profile_image;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your data classes are obfuscated. Use `@SerrializedName` of `@Keep` annotation to keep values readable

Comment: Yes I m also @SerrializedName but what is (@keep to keep values readable)?

Comment: `@Keep` is kotlin annotation

Comment: Are you using any encryption ? is the ProGauared active on your App? , Also what Backend technology is used for the API's?

Comment: @Enad no encryption is using and I also try to make active ProGauared active. API's are developed Laravel. And for authentication, they are using Passport.

Comment: @StanislavBondar no, I m using Java.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried below code and it works just set minifyEnabled false

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```